# How to get column edition in Pulsar text editor on Linux?

Tags: atom-editor, pulsar-editor

I recently tried to switch from Atom (that was fine for me) to Pulsar text editor.

I haven't figure out how to get column mode edition (aka multi-line) back on Linux.

Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

if you mean being able to click (Ctrl+shift+click) on several lines and edit them, I hope it helps, before switching to Pulsar, I uninstalled Atom, previously I saved the list of installed packages, then I deleted all the files related to it, the directory I think was called ".atom", I searched with "find" for any other related and deleted them, then I installed Pulsar.
It works as it should, although sometimes (few times actually) it doesn't work, I restart Pulsar and it works fine.